# PHP $_GET not working. trying to Get from user Table then Post in follow table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Using $_GET id to attempt to get the user id that i'm trying to follow then post it to the follows table isn't working however if i'm able to post the loggedin users id into the adjacent field in the same table.

This is for a mysql table that i'm trying to populate.

```
<?php
require_once("../../config.php");
include("../../classes/User.php");

if( isset($_SESSION['userLoggedIn']) && $_GET['id'] ) {
    $userLoggedIn = new User($con, $_SESSION['userLoggedIn']);

    if( !$database->has('follows', ['AND' => ['followFrom' =>      $userLoggedIn->id, 'followTo' => $_GET['id'] ]]) ) {
        $database->insert('follows', [
            'followFrom' => $userLoggedIn->id,
            'followTo' => $_GET['id']
        ]);
        echo 'followed';
    } else {
        $database->delete('follows', ['AND' => ['followFrom' => $userLoggedIn->id, 'followTo' => $_GET['id'] ]]);
        echo 'unfollowed';
    }

}
?>
```

expecting the user id I clicked to follow to be posted followTo field to be follows table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
require_once("../../config.php");
include("../../classes/User.php");

if( isset($_SESSION['userLoggedIn']) && **isset($_GET['id'])** ) {
    $userLoggedIn = new User($con, $_SESSION['userLoggedIn']);

    if( !$database->has('follows', ['AND' => ['followFrom' =>      $userLoggedIn->id, 'followTo' => $_GET['id'] ]]) ) {
        $database->insert('follows', [
            'followFrom' => $userLoggedIn->id,
            'followTo' => $_GET['id']
        ]);
        echo 'followed';
    } else {
        $database->delete('follows', ['AND' => ['followFrom' => $userLoggedIn->id, 'followTo' => $_GET['id'] ]]);
        echo 'unfollowed';
    }

}
?>
```

i think you missed the **isset** function.